# Microsoft Azure Backup (MARS) not running from scheduled tasks

Tags: windows, azure, backup

We've got several servers running MAR's the lastest version 2.0.9145.0

I can run all backup's manually and its runs without problems. But when i try to run it from scehduled backups it shows in task scheduler that its run but gives this error code:2147942401

If i manually input the arguements into powershell it runs fine. However the task scheduler is not kicking in the backups.

I've altered the permissions to a domain admin, changed PS path to syswow64. So now i'm lost.

Has anyone had similar and any ideas on how to fix it or at least run the commands from a bat file instead?

Comment: I believe code:2147942401 is an authentication code. You are able to execute the schedule task manually because it is executed with your user. This could be a group policy issue or privilege issue.

Comment: Thank you Rthomas529. Unfortunatly i've tried all the authentications that you can use created a script to auto login to azure each time and still nothing. When running the code on the server from task scheduler it runs fine. just seems like task sched is not working with azure.